# Overhead on looping over an iterable class

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking

I was fiddling around with Python's generators and iterable class, just for fun. Basically I wanted test out something that I've never been too sure about: that classes in Pythons have some significant overhead and it's better to rely on methods that implement `yield` instead of classes that implement an iterator protocol, if you can.

I couldn't find a satisfying explanation on this topic in Google, so I decided to test them out on my own using these two simple scripts: `func_iter.py` and `class_iter.py`

Here's `func_iter.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time  

x = 0
def create_generator(num):
    mylist = range(num)
    for i in mylist:
        yield i

t = time.time()
gen = create_generator(100000)

for i in gen:
    x = x + i

print "%.3f" % (time.time() - t)
```

And here's `class_iter.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

x = 0

class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.start = 0
        self.end = num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.start == self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.start = self.start + 1
            return self.start

t = time.time()
gen = Generator(100000)

for i in gen:
    x = x + i

print "%.3f" % (time.time() - t)
```

I then ran each of them 10 times using this in bash (for `class_iter.py`, for example):

```
for i in {1..10}; do ./class_iter.py; done
```

And here are the average running times for each of them:

```
class_iter.py: 0.0864
func_iter.py: 0.0307
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Are my methods correct? Is my comparison fair?
2. If so, why the big difference? Why did `class_iter.py` take almost three times as long as `func_iter.py` to run?
3. If not, how can I improve my methods or come up with a better comparison?

EDIT: As Dacav suggested, I also tried running `func_iter.py` using `xrange` instead of `range`. This decreases its average running time to 0.0263 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class version spends lots of time accessing its own variables. Each `self.whatever` costs cycles. If you define your `__iter__` as a generator and minimize the use of instance variables, the difference between class and function versions will be negligible:

```
setup = """
def create_generator(num):
    mylist = range(num)
    for i in mylist:
        yield i

class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.start = 0
        self.end = num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.start == self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.start = self.start + 1
            return self.start

class Generator2(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.mylist = range(num)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.mylist:
            yield i
"""

import timeit

print timeit.timeit('for p in create_generator(1000):p', setup, number=1000)
print timeit.timeit('for p in Generator(1000):p', setup, number=1000)
print timeit.timeit('for p in Generator2(1000):p', setup, number=1000)
```

Results:

```
0.158941984177
0.696810007095
0.160784959793
```

so the second generator class is almost as fast as the function version.

Please do note that `Generator` and `Generator2` in the example are not fully equivalent, there are cases when you cannot simply replace a "plain" iterator with a generator (e.g. marshaling).

Comment: I don't think that's what he wanted to test. You're comparing a generator to a generator here, not a generator to the iterator protocol. Yes, the class is still iterable, but (for example) you can't pickle it's state because the state is a generator that isn't a member of the class.

Comment: Confirmed! It's still slower for perhaps 0.002 seconds ~ is it safe to assume that this difference is due to the time it takes for the class to be instantiated?

Comment: @bow: yes, class instantiation + accessing the instance variable in `__iter__`. If you're curious to see what exactly is going on behind the scenes, try the `dis` module.

Comment: agf: Yes and no, I guess. I wasn't thinking about implementing a generator as the class method in the first place since I want to compare it to an actual class iterable. But I was curious about why it's slower. thg435 showed that it's because of instantiation times and attribute access ~ so I'm satisfied still :).


thg435: Thanks! I'm checking it now.

Comment: @agf: fair enough. I added a caveats to the post.

Comment: The overhead also (mainly) comes from function calls. For every iteration in the code not using generator, Python has to call the next() method which has to create the frame and local scope of the function. That takes time. A generator also has a frame and local scope but they're created once and reused for every iteration.

Comment: create_generator is obviously a generator, Generator is an iterator and Generator2 is iterable. Is that right?

Comment: @mdob: yes, this is correct. Generator2 is an Iterable whose `__iter__` returns an implicit Iterator object, with `__iter__` and `next` created behind the scenes by the means of `yield`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python there are good chances you are not aiming at software performance, but you care more about being rapid and agile in development.

Said that, I think the comparison method is quite fair as long as your code is smart enough to avoid bias for one solution.

For instance, a possible improvement for the `yield`-based version could be removing the `range` function ad use the `xrange` function instead. The difference (in python 2.x) is that `range` builds a list of values (so it must allocate space in memory for it) while `xrange` builds an iterable object ranging on the given values.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this, and the average time for ``func_iter.py`` now decreases to 0.0263.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be completely correct and your comparison is fair. When you compare only overhead, the class supporting the iterator protocol will be slower than a generator function.

However, in the real world, if the code is complicated enough to justify a class, *the running time of the algorithm will dwarf the overhead*, and so it will be completely irrelevant to the runtime of your program.

You're worrying about micro-optimizations here. You shouldn't. Focus on writing good, readable code, and using the right algorithm for the job. The amount of time spent on attribute lookups and method calls in the class version will not be your bottleneck.

Comment: Ah :), my intention was not really optimizing a production code (although this might relate a bit). I was just curious about something I've long thought before (but never really proven) ~ and I'm sure you know busting myths is fun :D.

Comment: @bow I'm trying to say you're asking the wrong question. It doesn't matter what the speed difference is, within reason. What matters is picking the method that makes your code better. You're right that one is slower, but wrong that you should be thinking about that _at all_.

Comment: @bow It's also worth noting that this is a site for real problems, not theoretical ones (see the FAQ), so you're bound to get at least some answers that address the question as if it was not just academic.